# CSS Button sizing

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons on a screen that have their sizes set, based on their padding. When a word is wrapped,  the associated button gets taller as you would expect. The problem is now though that i have different sized buttons. I don't want to set them to a specific height but for them to be responsive based on the text and would like them to all be the same height.

Is there any way that you can have all buttons as tall as the tallest one.

Comment: Show us some html/css to get your problem solved!

Comment: Paste a bit of CSS and HTML to see your structure and what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of alignment, I use *flex* layout
It's supported by major browsers https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css3_flexbox.asp

```
<div style="display:flex;">
<button>Button 1
</button>
<button style="font-style:2em;">Button 2
</button>
<button>Button 3
</button>
</div>
```

See :
https://jsfiddle.net/rw0a4p5j/4/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure just adding `display: flex;` to the container of the buttons would do that automatically :

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>Test</button>
    <button>Test<br> Test</button>
    <button>Test</button>
</div>
```